# Set limit to a number dynamically

Tags: c#

I have a database field on oracle, named quantity. It is created as `number(4)`.
I want to make a validation for the user, I want to say to the user

> "You can not insert a number bigger than 9999"

But I want to do this *dynamically*. When somebody changed the database field to `number(5)`, this validation should say

> "You can not insert a number bigger than 99999".

I'm using LLBLGen as an ORM tool. I have the length of the field as TableFields.Quantity.MaxLenght. It is 4.

Is there a way at C# to get the *max number* for a fields *max length*?

I can write a method which creates the *max number* from the length `4`, but is there a method in C# which makes it for me?

```
if (request.Quantity.ToString().Length > TableFields.Quantity.MaxLength)
  response.Notifications.Add(NotificationType.Error, 
                            "You can not insert a number bigger than {0}", 
                             9999);
```

Comment: `Math.Pow(10, number) - 1`? E.g. `TableFields.Quantity.MaxLenght = 4` and `Math.Pow(10, TableFields.Quantity.MaxLenght) - 1 == 9999`

Comment: What you mean in `C#`? Yes, there is probably some library somewhere, that has method which will do what you want, but there is nothing wrong to write it by yourself.

Comment: @SeM: no need to rewrite `Math.Pow`

Comment: @Rango In OP's case (s)he should probably have some method called `GetMaxNumber(int limit) => Math.Pow(10, limit) -1;`, I didn't think at first (s)he was asking math question (it's kind of off topic).

Comment: @SeM I was searching a method like you said, something like GetMaxNumber(), but Dmitry Bychenko's answer was great enough. I didn't think about using math functions at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for some *math*?

```
10**number - 1
```

In your case

```
var maxValue = Math.Pow(10, TableFields.Quantity.MaxLength) - 1;
```

If `TableFields.Quantity.MaxLength == 4` then `maxValue == 9999`